# Get start and end value on X axis when selecting interval with mouse on chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

CursorX SelectionStart and SelectionEnd are returning NaN, when selecting interval on chart. I would like to know how can I retrieve values from selecting chart area with mouse, in C# WinForms.

I can select interval already, but I cant take start and end value. 
Probably I am missing to implement some mouse event, but I couldn't find solution myself yet.

```
chartArea.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
var cx = chartArea.CursorX;
double x1 = cx.SelectionStart;
double x2 = cx.SelectionEnd;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must subscribe to the `Chart.SelectionRangeChanged` event and handle it something like this:

```
private void chart_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
{
    if (!double.IsNaN(e.NewSelectionStart) && !double.IsNaN(e.NewSelectionEnd))
    {
        double x1 = e.NewSelectionStart;
        double x2 = e.NewSelectionEnd;

        // Do something with x1 and x2. 
        // Note that x1 > x2 if the user selected from right to left.
```

You would normally subscribe to this event via the form editor, but if for some reason you can't do that, then the following code will subscribe (assuming that `_chart` is your chart object):

```
_chart.SelectionRangeChanged += chart_SelectionRangeChanged;
```

Do that in the form constructor after the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, but I cant fire event (cant enter this method on selecting interval on chart), where would you add event handler?